# How to find loop running last time?

Tags: java, jsp

I'm generating markup in `c:forEach` loop. How can I determine that this loop is running last time so that I can generate some extra markup according to my requirement?

```
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.leadListIs}" var="leadList">
    <li>Test</li>
    <!-- if this loop running final time then -->
    <li>Last</li>
    <!-- end-if -->
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: cant you just put the `<li>Last</li>` after the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.leadListIs}" var="leadList" varStatus="status">
     ${status.last ? '<li>Last</li>' : '<li>Test</li>'}
</c:forEach>
```

Regards